# no such file or directory: org-eldoc

Tags: org-mode, eldoc, org-roam

I recently discovered that my `org-roam` installation is no longer working.  When I try to open a new file, I get this error message:

```
helm-M-x-execute-command: Cannot open load file: No such file or directory, org-eldoc
```

I'm not sure how my `org-eldoc` got corrupted, but what would be the easiest way to repair it?

Comment: AFAIK, `org-eldoc` exists in `contrib` only. Have you installed `org-plus-contrib`? Have you set your `load-path` to include the `contrib` directory? What *is* the value of your `load-path`? What happens if you say `M-x load-library RET org-eldoc RET`?

Comment: @NickD. When I try to load `org-eldoc` I get `no such file or directory, org-eldoc`.  After installing `org-plus-contrib`, I was able to access `org-roam` again.  But after exiting emacs and starting again, I had the same problem.  Not sure how to get `org-plus-contrib` to stick around after exiting.

Comment: I'm sure it sticks around after exiting. Just make sure that your `load-path` is set in your init file properly. I have `(add-to-list 'load-path (expand-file-name "~/elisp/org-mode/lisp"))

(add-to-list 'load-path (expand-file-name "~/elisp/org-mode/contrib/lisp"))` in my init file, but you'll need to change the paths for your setup.

Comment: @NickD. I have a few additions to my load path, like `(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/packages")`. How can I tell if my load path isn't set properly?  My packages have always loaded until I had this problem.

Comment: Let's try this: can you find out where exactly the `org-eldoc.el` (or `org-eldoc.elc`) file is? Then add that directory to your `load-path`? E.g. I just did a `package-install-packages`, selected `org-plus-contrib` with `i` and then installed it with `x`. It ended up in `~/.emacs.d/elpa/org-plus-contrib-20210104` and the package installation added `"/home/nick/.emacs.d/elpa/org-plus-contrib-20210104"` to the front of my load-path. If I now do `M-x locate-library RET org-eldoc`, I get `Library is file ~/.emacs.d/elpa/org-plus-contrib-20210104/org-eldoc.elc`. Can you try that?

Comment: Edit your question and add all these details: don't reply in a comment.